# FontAwesome Icons Not showing up when used with PrimeNg Module

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, primeng

I have installed angular-fontawesome using the instructions here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

The icons show up when used in this fashion (app.component.html):

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <!-- simple name only that assumes the 'fas' prefix -->
        <fa-icon icon="coffee"></fa-icon>
        <!-- ['fas', 'coffee'] is an array that indicates the [prefix, iconName] -->
        <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'coffee']"></fa-icon>
        <fa-icon [icon]="['fa', 'fa-fw', 'fa-book']"></fa-icon>
      </div>
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/menu';
import { TabMenuModule } from 'primeng/tabmenu';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

import { TestcomponentComponent } from './testcomponent/testcomponent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestcomponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ButtonModule,
    MenuModule,
    TabMenuModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor() {
        // Add an icon to the library for convenient access in other components
        library.add(fas, far);
  }
}
```

However, I get no icons when integrating it with a PrimeNg Module (in this case their TabMenuModule). Not doing anything unusual, just following the instructions here:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabmenu

```
app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ClientApp';

  private items: MenuItem[];

        ngOnInit() {
          this.items = [
            {label: 'Overview', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart'},
            {label: 'Schedule', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-calendar'},
            {label: 'Documentation', icon: 'fa-coffee'},
            {label: 'Support', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-support'},
            {label: 'Discussion', icon: 'fa fa-fw fa-twitter'}
        ];
      }
```

I add these lines to top of the html:

```
<h3 class="first">Default</h3>
    <p-tabMenu [model]="items1" [activeItem]="items1[0]"></p-tabMenu>

    <h3>Templating</h3>
    <p-tabMenu [model]="items2" [activeItem]="activeItem">
        <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item let-i="index">
            <div style="position: relative; text-align: center; min-width: 10em">
                <div class="ui-menuitem-icon" [ngClass]="item.icon" *ngIf="item.icon" style="font-size: 2em"></div>
                <div class="ui-menuitem-text">
                    {{item.label}}
                </div>
                <a tabindex="0" class="ui-menuitem-icon" (click)="closeItem($event, i)" style="position: absolute; right: -1em; top: -.5em; padding: 0" *ngIf="i !== 0">
                    <span class="pi pi-times"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-tabMenu>
<p-tabMenu [model]="items"></p-tabMenu>
<i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>
```

angular.json:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ClientApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

I am using: 
Angular CLI: 8.0.2
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0
angular-fontawesome@0.4.0
free-solid-svg-icons@5.9.0
free-regular-svg-icons@5.9.0

Comment: use that https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: I think you are missing primeicons, install `npm install primeicons` add primicons css to angular.json `"node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"`

Comment: @Goku did you find any solution, I am also stuck in a similar situation.  I want to use angular-fontawesome icons in primeNg Menubar.

Comment: This was almost 2 years ago so I don't remember if I solved it or found a workaround, but I would recommend tryingthe comment made by @ElasticCode comment of installing primeicons and adding primeicons.css to see if that helps the issue. I upvoted his answer so there is a good chance that worked (I should have updated this answer either way... big fowl on my part)

Comment: @manjeetlama did you find a solution for this issue - adding primeicons will make use of primeicons and not fontawesome icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these css entries into your styles.scss file, that is what it took in my case.

```
@import  "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import  "~primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
@import  "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import  "~primeflex/primeflex.css";
```